# Find emails and convert them to HTML links using UNIX command

Tags: html, unix, sed

I am trying to find command which would find all emails in the file and convert them to HTML links. Any ideas?

input would be:

```
<tr>
    <td>Some Position</td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td>some@email.com</td>
    <td>Some phone number</td>
</tr>
```

I want output:

```
<tr>
    <td>Some Position</td>
    <td>Some Name</td>
    <td><a href="mailto:some@email.com">some@email.com</a></td>
    <td>Some phone number</td>
</tr>
```

I tried:

```
sed -i -e "s|\w+@\w+\.\w+(\.\w+)?|<a href=\"mailto:\0\">\0</a>|g" emails.txt
```

Comment: I added input/output, I tried: `sed -i -e "s|\w+@\w+\.\w+(\.\w+)?|<a href=\"mailto:\0\">\0</a>|g" emails.txt` but it didnt seem to work

Comment: OK, great. I updated your question with this comment and added `sed` tag.

Comment: @JavaNoob, `sed` references start from `\1`, not `\0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`LOCAL="[\._-+a-zA-Z0-9]"`

`HOST="[\._-+a-zA-Z0-9]"`

`EXT=".*"`

`EMAIL="$LOCAL*@$HOST*\.$EXT"`

`sed "s|\($EMAIL\)|<a href=\"mailto:\1\">\1</a>|g" emails.txt`

You could add more validation to the first three variables.

Comment: I imagine "s/" is in fact "s|". Nice wayt to make sed formula readeable. EXT is also maybe "[^<]*"

Answer (score 0):

A little perl might do:

```
perl -pe 's/\W*(\w+@\w+)\W*/<A HREF="mailto:$1">$1<\/A>/'
```

Feed file for this with e.g. cat or just with `< your.file.html` and see what happens. You probably might have to fiddle a bit with the regexp related, in case your input is not strictly as in your example.